# GAE flex Connection String to first generation CloudSQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-flexible

I have a GAE flex application that uses sqlalchemy/mysql.  I also have a Google CloadSQL mysql instance First Generation.  Is it possible to connect a GAE flex environment to a First Generation CloudSQL instance without connecting as an external app (and thus needing to whitelist the world).  The Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) states to use `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` as the connection string.  I've tried many different flavors, but I'm still unsuccessful.

Examples:

`mysql+pymysql://user:password@/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
mysql+pymysql:///cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`

Is there a different driver that's needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is not possible to connect GAE flex to CloudSQL 1st generation.

The alternatives are:

a. Use App Engine Standard App instead.

b. Migrate the First Generation instance to a [Second Generation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen) one

Answer (score 0):

After searching the various Google documents, IRC channels and Slack forums, i've come to the conclusion that CloudSQL Gen 1 isn't support on GAE:flex :(